# Error at Monadic TicTacToe in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I started to implement TicTacToe in Haskell:

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Player = X | O
data Field = Player | I deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data GameField = G [[Field]]

type GameState = State GameField ()

initGame :: GameState
initGame = do
    put $ G [[I,I,I],[I,I,I],[I,I,I]]

action = do
    initGame

test = execState action $ G [[I,I,I],[I,I,I],[I,I,I]]
```

When I execute "test" I get the following Error:

```
No instance for (Show GameField) arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show GameField)
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What is the cause of this problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually not a too cryptic message. If there is no `Show` instance, add one:

```
data GameField = G [[Field]] deriving (Show)
```

Comment: For the record: most often when GHC complains about missing instances, that's _not_ actually the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot to add 'deriving show' on your GameField decleration.. This would simply be solved by adding it, like this

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Player = X | O
data Field = Player | I deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data GameField = G [[Field]]
  deriving Show

type GameState = State GameField ()

initGame :: GameState
initGame = do
    put $ G [[I,I,I],[I,I,I],[I,I,I]]

action = do
    initGame

test = execState action $ G [[I,I,I],[I,I,I],[I,I,I]]
```